# Network Manager Fails to Maintain A Long-Term Connection on 802.11x Networks

Tags: networking, network-manager

I'm good with bugs, but I can't remain connected to an 802.11x Enterprise grade network.  It uses `Tunneled TLS` authentication, with `PAP` inner authentication.

It will connect, but then go and randomly disconnect me and then go insane, and go into a cycle of me needing to re-authenticate with the network.  But then it won't re-authenticate, until I use the hardware switch to turn off the card, then turn it back on and then it connects, but then disconnects again.

I need a little bit of help troubleshooting this, because on the network here, i can't use Ubuntu, so I'm stuck on Windows until I debug it.

How do I go about debugging this?

The card's an Intel WLAN card on a Dell Latitude E6500.  It uses the `iwlagn` or similar driver.  It is not a Broadcom card, and the wifi works on every other type of network.

Answer (score 1):

Have seen this when Network usage is high, or when the network switches get loaded in an Enterprise network, or the admins are testing the network. Would suggest that any logs from the system would be helpful to have though. Can you gather the output from /var/log/messages and see if there are errors there?

You can also check [this site](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_%3a_Ch13_%3a_Linux_Wireless_Networking#.Ufvt8eZDuXc) for some well-written debugging and troubleshooting tips.

Comment: I replaced the built in wifi card with a Wireless N USB adapter and apparently that works better... but I'll test next time I"m back on that network to see what's up with it.  The problem I think is that it has to do with the ~250 systems in the area on the access point and the high net usage causes auth timeouts...

Comment: Sounds like the right approach for the drops. Would suggest looking at the wifi tools available, kismet might help.